# Compactness of the identity operator

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, compact-operators

As far as I know, by [Rellich-Kondrachov theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem), we can say $I:H_{0}^{k}\to H_{0}^{m}$, for $m<k$ is a compact operator, where
$H_{0}^{k}=\{f\in H_{{}}^{k}|f(0)={f}'(0)=\cdots ={{f}^{(k)}}(0)=0\}$.

I am wondering if it is possible to say that the operator $I:H_{0}^{k}\to H_{0}^{k}$ is a compact operator?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rellich Kondrachov gives different embedding theorem; be ware of compact and continuous embedding. for some k the embedding is continuous but not compact.

Answer (score 7):

No. The identity operator is not compact in any infinite dimensional Banach space.

Comment: Yes Exactly, 
The more precise answer is that when $k\ge m+1/2$ the Rellich Kondrachov theorem works.